# How to fit my website content on any screen either on full screen or not

Tags: html

Im writing my site on my PC at a 1920*1080 resolution and i adjust everything to look good when i open my html file . When i open the html from another computer(for example :my laptop) with 720p resolution, the site looks terrible and all the photos,texts,links ..etch are almost one inside of another. It's like the html working only at 1080p resolution and if someone comes with larger or smaller one , the site isnt adjusting to you resolutions. Can you tell me what is the missing code that helps the website adjust on its own at any resolution and where exactly i should add this part of code? My "style" code is

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
 html
 {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }

 welcome
  {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

  } 
.header img 
    {
      position: sticky;
      left: 540px;
      width: 800px;
      height: 200px;
      align-content: center;
    }
ul
    {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

li 
{
  float: left;
}

li a
    {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px 35px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

li a:hover:not(.active) 
    {
      background-color: #111;
    }

.active 
      {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
      }
.rightbar
      {
        float:right;
      }
.cake
      {
        position: relative;
        left: 4%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 380px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }
.cake1
      {
        position: relative;
        left: 25%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 380px;
        bottom:38%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }
.cake2
      {
        position: relative;
        left: 60%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 380px;
        bottom:76%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }
.cake3
      {
        position: relative;
        left: 80%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 380px;
        bottom:114%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }
.product_a
      {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f4511e;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0.3s;
        left:25px;

      }
.product_a:hover
    {
    opacity: 0.6;
    }
#section1
    {
      height:1000px;
    }
#section2
    {
      height: 1000px;


    }
```

Comment: A lot of your CSS styles are using fixed widths (i.e. `width: 320px;`) instead of dynamic widths (i.e. `width: 100%;` or `width: 50%`). Using fixed widths is fine, but using dynamic widths makes switching to different device sizes a lot easier.

Comment: You should be doing your own research before seeking help here, as it is a very common problem for which tons of tutorials already exist and are very easy to find using your favorite search engine. Please feel free to ask if you stumble across a problem you can't solve while following those tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

With media queries, you can control how your page is styled for different resolutions.

For example:

```
/* If the browser window is 720px or smaller, the background color will be lightblue */
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```